# Prevent wget from placing linebreaks in file titles?

Tags: linux, shell, wget

When I run the following command:

```
wget http://mywebsite.com/app/count.php -O count.txt
```

I noticed the following:

```
Saving to: ‘count.txt\r’
```

wget is placing linebreaks into my filenames! Is there any way I can prevent this?

Thank-you for your time.

Comment: If that wget command is in a script file, and the file has DOS-style line endings, then the carriage return will get appended to the filename.

Comment: Thank-you very much! I've found a solution based off of your advice. I've changed the command format, now I'm running: 
wget -O "count.txt" http://mywebsite.com/app/count.php

Comment: You should fix the file format instead: use `dos2unix` on that file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved in comments. This answer is an extract for future users with similar problem.

Probable cause:

> If that `wget` command is in a script file, and the file has DOS-style line endings, then the carriage return will get appended to the filename.

This is because Linux (Unix-like system in general) expects `\n` (another notation: `LF`) as a line ending. DOS and Windows use `\r\n` (`CR+LF`). This additional `\r` is interpreted by Linux as any normal character – as a part of the line, in this case as a part of the filename.

More information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

OP's solution:

> `wget -O "count.txt"`

It might solve this particular problem, but the additional `\r` is probably still there at the end, not as a part of filename though. The general, recommended solution:

> You should fix the file format instead: use `dos2unix` on that file.